# what is different between datagrid and sqlgrid in apache ignite?

Tags: datagrid, ignite

I am exploring apache ignite for caching data in memory (data comes from different sources e.g. mysql, mongo etc). My use case is to be able to cache large number of columns (starting with ~1000) for each row. I should be able to query, sort, paginate data quickly.

I am exploring if apache ignite can fit for the use case. But there are 2 options i) Data grid (key-value cache) ii) Sql grid (uses h2db parser).

Which one to choose for which use cases ?

Is apache ignite suitable for caching data which has rows and columns like in RDBMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, Ignite SQL Grid is a set of APIs which allow you working with distributed data using familiar SQL syntax. The data is always stored in Ignite Data Grid in a form of key-value tuples.

Both SQL and Data grid are tightly coupled and you use both of them if you need to store data in an Ignite cluster and query it or update using SQL syntax.